# Duplicate question that is not a duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[FileUpload with JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797650/fileupload-with-jax-rs)

is marked as a duplicate of

[Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java)

but isn't.  I don't have a gold badge on tag [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), nor am I the original asker of the question, is there a way to dispute the duplicate marking?

Edit:
The `FileUpload` with JAX-RS question is how to annotate methods so that a file can be received by  a server, typically in the form of an `InputStream`.  Converting said `InputStream` to a byte array is resolved by the *"Convert InputStream to byte array in Java"* question.  It is a typical follow on question, but it is not the same question.

Comment: you can always flag the question for moderator intervention and let them know the question is not duplicate and they will decide.

Comment: Don't flag for moderator, they already enough of work and may not have domain knowledge. Instead you can try to ping the gold badge that have closed it, enter a chat room (tag related or general moderation room) and ask for advice or post on meta as you have done. It's better that *"normal"* community members handle this kind of problems.

Comment: *and yes I agree that it's not a good duplicate and since I have more then >3K reputation I have voted to reopen*